# Most efficient way to parse a file in Lua

Tags: performance, optimization, lua

I'm trying to figure out what is the most efficient way to parse data from a file using Lua. For example lets say I have a file (example.txt) with something like this in it:

```
0, Data
74, Instance
4294967295, User
255, Time
```

If I only want the numbers before the "," I could think of a few ways to get the information. I'd start out by getting the data with `f = io.open(example.txt)` and then use a for loop to parse each line of `f`. This leads to the heart of my question. What is the most efficient way to do this?

In the for loop I could use any of these methods to get the # before the comma:

```
line.find(regex)
line:gmatch(regex)
line:match(regex)
```

or Lua's [split function](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin)

Has anyone run test for speed for these/other methods which they could point out as the fast way to parse? Bonus points if you can speak to speeds for parsing small vs. large files.

Comment: Please don't confuse between [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) and [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/LUA). Both languages are different. "Lua" is a name, and means "Moon" in Portugese. Please do not write it as "LUA", which is both ugly and confusing, because then it becomes an acronym with [different meanings](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/lua) for different people.

Comment: I suspect that all of these will get similar performance (in which case just use whatever is simpler/clearer for you). The cost of the file IO and reading from a hard drive probably dwarfs the simple O(N) processing that you do with the lines.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `line:match("%d+")`.

`line:find` would work as well but returns more than you want.

`line:gmatch` is not what you need because it is meant to match several items in a string, not just one, and is meant to be used in a loop.

As for speed, you'll have to make your own measurements. Start with the simple code below:

```
for line in io.lines("example.txt") do
  local x=line:match("%d+")
  if x~=nil then print(x) end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as I mentioned I'm familiar with how to use match but it's running the speed test which I don't know how to preform so this doesn't quite answer my question. Thanks for the input though!