# Lua: Parsing and Manipulating Input with Loops - Looking for Guidance

Tags: string, parsing, loops, lua

I am currently attempting to parse data that is sent from an outside source serially.  An example is as such:

```
DATA|0|4|7x5|1|25|174-24|7x5|1|17|TERW|7x5|1|9|08MN|7x5|1|1|_
```

This data can come in many different lengths, but the first few pieces are all the same.  Each "piece" originally comes in with CRLF after, so I've replaced them with `string.gsub(input,"\r\n","|")` so that is why my input looks the way it does.

The part I would like to parse is:

```
4|7x5|1|25|174-24|7x5|1|17|TERW|7x5|1|9|08MN|7x5|1|1|_
```

The "4" tells me that there will be four lines total to create this file.  I'm using this as a means to set the amount of passes in the loop.
The 7x5 is the font height.
The 1 is the xpos.
The 25 is the ypos.
The variable data (172-24 in this case) is the text at these parameters.
As you can see, it should continue to loop this pattern throughout the input string received.  Now the "4" can actually be any variable > 0; with each number equaling a set of four variables to capture.

Here is what I have so far.  Please excuse the `loop` variable, `start` variable, and `print` commands.  I'm using Linux to run this function to try to troubleshoot.

```
function loop_input(input)
  var = tonumber(string.match(val, "DATA|0|(%d*).*"))
  loop = string.match(val, "DATA|0|")
  start = string.match(val, loop.."(%d*)|.*")
  for obj = 1, var do
    for i = 1, 4 do
        if i == 1 then
          i = "font" -- want the first group to be set to font
        elseif i == 2 then
          i = "xpos" -- want the second group to be set to xpos
        elseif i == 3 then
          i = "ypos" -- want the third group to be set to ypos
        else
          i = "txt" -- want the fourth group to be set to text
        end
      obj = font..xpos..ypos..txt
      --print (i)
    end
  objects = objects..obj -- concatenate newly created obj variables with each pass
  end
end

val = "DATA|0|4|7x5|1|25|174-24|7x5|1|17|TERW|7x5|1|9|08MN|7x5|1|1|_"

print(loop_input(val))
```

Ideally, I want to create a loop that, depending on the `var` variable, will plug in the captured variables between the pipe deliminators and then I can use them freely as I wish.  When trying to troubleshoot with parenthesis around my four variables (like I have above), I receive the full list of four variables four times in a row.  Now I'm having difficulty actually cycling through the input string and actually grabbing them out as the loop moves down the data string.  I was thinking that using the pipes as a means to delineate variables from one another would help.  Am I wrong?  If it doesn't matter and I can keep the `[/r/n]+` instead of each `"|"` then I am definitely all for that.

I've searched around and found some threads that I thought would help but I'm not sure if tables or splitting the inputs would be advisable.  Like these threads:

[Setting a variable in a for loop (with temporary variable) Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264838/setting-a-variable-in-a-for-loop-with-temporary-variable-lua)

[How do I make a dynamic variable name in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061755/how-do-i-make-a-dynamic-variable-name-in-lua)

[Most efficient way to parse a file in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026530/most-efficient-way-to-parse-a-file-in-lua)

I'm fairly new to programming and trying to teach myself.  So please excuse my beginner thread.  I have both the "Lua Reference Manual" and "Programming in Lua" books in paperback which is how I've tried to mock my function(s) off of.  But I'm having a problem making the connection.

I thank you all for any input or guidance you can offer!

Cheers.

Comment: Your `loop_input` is rather confusing. Your `input` argument isn't used at all and you're reassigning your loop counter inside the loop body -- that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the input greatwolf.  I was trying to slowly build my code in hopes to get it working but continued to end up short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val = "DATA|0|4|7x5|1|25|174-24|7x5|1|17|TERW|7x5|1|9|08MN|7x5|1|1|_"
val = val .. "|"
data = val:match("DATA|0|%d+|(.*)$")  
for fh,xpos,ypos,text in data:gmatch("(.-)|(.-)|(.-)|(.-)|") do
    print(fh,xpos,ypos,text)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help lhf.  I'm trying to use the code you provided above and I keep getting errors with the for loop "attempt to call a string value".  If I break it down, I understand what the code is doing.  If I note out the for loop, and print the variables just before them, they are captured and returned as intended.  So right now I'm having an issue parsing the `data` variable into the four smaller variables.  Looking at your code, it makes sense now that I understand how you went about it.  Although, will this continue to grab the variables as long as they are there?

Comment: @Pwrcdr87, the code I gave works fine in the [Lua live demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html). Anyway, the loop will keeping on working  while there are four fields to be extracted from the string.

Comment: I found my problem.  I forgot the "g" at `data:gmatch`.  Thanks again for all of the help!